# Maintaining ordering in multithreaded apache camel application

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

We use `Tibco EMS` as our messaging system and have used `apache camel` to write our application. In our application, messages are written to a queue. A component, with `concurrentConsumers` set to 8, reads from the queue, processes the message, then writes to another queue. Another component, again with `concurrentConsumers` set to 8, then reads from this new queue and so on. Up until now, maintaining message order has not been important, but a new requirement means that it now is. Looking at the camel documentation, it is suggested that `jmsxgroupid` is used to maintain ordering. Unfortunately, this functionality is not available with `Tibco EMS`. Are there any other ways of maintaining ordering in camel in a multithreaded application? I have looked at sticky load balancing, but this seems to be applicable to end point load balancing only.

Thanks

Bruce

Comment: Concurrent execution cannot ensure order... Especially when task require different amount of time to execute... EG network operation, like sending messages...

Comment: Check out the resequencer EIP at this link: http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html

Comment: Why should jmsxgroupid not work with TIBCO EMS? its part of the JMS spec that was supported from day on (have a look at the docs)

Answer (score 3):

In the enterprise integration world, we generally use the [Resequencer](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Resequencer.html) design pattern to solve such kind of problems that you need to ensure ordering in the messages.

Apache Camel covers a broad extent of the Enterprise Integration Patterns including Resequencer at its core and it has out-of-the-box imprementations for those patterns. So what you are looking for should be this:
http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html

In your specific case, all you need to do would be add a custom message header like `myMessageNo`, which has a sequential number that specifies the ordering, to outgoing messages to TIBCO EMS. Then, at consumer side, use the resequencer EIP to restore the ordering of incoming messages from TIBCO EMS.

As you can see, however, it's not as easy as just putting the resequencer EIP to your Camel routes. (Any asynchronous solutions are always hard to build correctly.) For the resequencer, you need to consider when sad paths happen, e.g. when some messages get lost and never reach. To make sure your routes work fine even with those exceptional cases, you need to choose from two options: maximum batch size or timeout. Depending on the condition chosen, the resequenser will flush messages when the batch reaches the maximum size or it timeouts waiting for a missing message.